# Bash: Sourcing another .sh file auto execute unwanted commands

Tags: bash, import

I have been trying to source a group of files by listing files in their directory and sourcing them one by one. Wierdly bash is auto executing a "command option" as a function before and after reading each script.

```
function source_files_under_dir () {
d="$1"
    for f in $DOTFILES/.$d/*; do
        if [ -f "$f" ]; then
            echo "[INFO] ... Sourcing $f"
            source $f
            echo "[INFO] ... Completed."
        fi
    done
}
source_files_under_dir lib
```

output:

```
[INFO] ... Sourcing /Users/ial-ah/GitHub/dotfiles/.lib/files
-bash: lib: command not found
[INFO] ... Completed.
[INFO] ... Sourcing /Users/ial-ah/GitHub/dotfiles/.lib/find
-bash: lib: command not found
[INFO] ... Completed.
[INFO] ... Sourcing /Users/ial-ah/GitHub/dotfiles/.lib/files
-bash: lib: command not found
[INFO] ... Completed.
[INFO] ... Sourcing /Users/ial-ah/GitHub/dotfiles/.lib/find
-bash: lib: command not found
[INFO] ... Completed.
```

as you see my script is running twice and try to run lib command ( which exists only on source_file_dir as it argument

Note that none of the files find and found contain a "lib" function command or variable. Can anyone notice what's happening here ?

Comment: What version of `bash` are you using? I can't replicate the exact behavior you're getting. On `4.4.12` it works as expected. Are you perhaps running this on Windows with `git-bash`?

Comment: Well, I tried it on `git-bash` and there's no issues there either. Is this part of something bigger?

Comment: I am actually using bash 3.2.4 on macOS, I realize I have an old version now but should be this problem of the version even if its just simple bash script ?

Comment: there is nothing bigger, the files 'files' and 'find' contain simple functions with `$@` at the end

Comment: It is actually possible that this is a bash bug. I've found a bug like this on another question. However, I think your use of `$@` might be a clue. Try replacing `files` and `find` with something that just has a simple `echo` in it, just so you separate this function from those, so you can see if it's this one that has the issue or those. If it only happens when you source those files, it may actually be that the `lib` string is passed as an argument, since those files are sourced and will inherit the arguments of the script sourcing them.

Comment: By the way, in case you're interested, I think `brew` on OSX provides a more recent `bash` version. OSX doesn't come with it by default due to licensing.

Comment: This worked when I removed the the $@ ! it was clearly version bug as you said

Comment: Yes I should upgrade my bash I just never thought I ll need a newer bash version ! Thanks buddy !

Comment: If removing the `$@` worked, it's _not_ a version bug! You need to `shift` the `lib` argument off the argument list before passing `$@` to your sourced functions!